# How to refresh a ListView from a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver, notifydatasetchanged

If I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the custom adapter associated to my ListView, all the views should refresh themself (`getView()` will be called).
Now I have a BroadcastReceiver that is listening to an event. When the event fires, the ListView must be refreshed. How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: "Now I have a BroadcastReceiver that is listening to an event" -- what is the event, and how is the `BroadcastReceiver` registered (manifest or `registerReceiver()`)?

Comment: Hi, dinamically registered in the Activity that contains the ListView, the event is ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE from the DownloadManager.

Comment: in onReceive of BroadcastReceiver implementation you have to: modify underlying data of your custom adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged or create new custom adapter and set it to listview

Comment: @Selvin it could be easy if i would have access to the listview from the receiver. I could call getAdapter. I don't know how to access the listview from the receiver (avoiding static or getters)

Comment: you said that you have dynamic Reciver from activity... so i think that code looks like http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/ then you **have** access to the listview inside onReceive (findViewById(R.id.id_of_listview) should work since this implementation will be not static inner class of Activity)

Comment: Add an interface (which is implemented by your activity/fragment). Pass the interface instance, when creating the broadcast receiver, when you receive broadcast (i.e. onReceive()), make a call on the interface, e.g. mDataUpdateListener.onDataAvailable(newData)

Comment: @Selvin it's not like Vogella as the BroadcastReceiver is declared in a separate class file, not inside the Activity. It's like registerReceiver(new DownloadReceiver(), new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)); in onCreate() and DownloadReceiver is not declared inside the same Activity

Comment: @GauravArora could you write an example as an answer?

Comment: will post in a moment.

Comment: Please see the answer section for detailed sample, I havn't compiled or ran this yet, but once you fix any required initialization and correct assumption, the solution should work well.

Answer (score 2):

If you refresh listview from receiver you'll have code like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver br;
public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "BROADCAST_ACTION";
br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//code refreshing...
}
};
IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
```

And you call it with code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If you need the refresh to be another action you just need to add (after action):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Its not working properly . Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: I think the "//code refreshing..." part is the hard part here.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, please see the sample code below:

```
public interface OnDataUpdateListener {
    void onDataAvailable(ArrayList<String> newDataList);
}

public class MyTestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String DATA_LIST = "DATA_LIST";
    private OnDataUpdateListener mDataUpdateListener = null;
    public MyTestReceiver(OnDataUpdateListener dataUpdateListener) {
        mDataUpdateListener = dataUpdateListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        // assuming data is available in the delivered intent
        ArrayList<String> dataList = intent.getSerializableExtra(DATA_LIST);
        if (null != mDataUpdateListener) {
            mDataUpdateListener.onDataAvailable(dataList);
        }
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnDataUpdateListener {
    public static final String ACTION_DATA_UPDATE_READY = "ACTION_DATA_UPDATE_READY";
    private MyTestReceiver mTestReceiver = null;
    private <SomeAdapterClass> mAdapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // other required initialization 
        mTestReceiver = new MyTestReceiver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (null != mTestReceiver) {
            registerReceiver(mTestReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_DATA_UPDATE_READY));
        }
    }

    void onDataAvailable(ArrayList<String> newDataList) {
        // assuming you want to replace existing data and not willing to append to existing dataset
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(newDataList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code where your data is updated, fire off a message signalling that data has been changed...
(You will need access to either the Activity or the Application context to do this)

```
Intent intent = new Intent("ListViewDataUpdated");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context.sendBroadcast(intent));
```

Then just catch the catch the message using the following code in your activity, and tell your ListAdapter to update...

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
        };

@Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("ListViewDataUpdated"));
  myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//in case our data was updated while this activity was paused
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
   super.onPause();
}
```

Credit: adapted from Vogella

Answer (score 0):

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context.sendBroadcast(intent));

change to

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);

I might be wrong but it works for me...